# How can I do paired t-tests in R with multiple variables?

Tags: r, t-test

I am wanting to run paired t-tests on multiple variables (left vs right measurements) but am also wanting to then divide it up by sex and do a paired t-test for males to compare to the females. Is this possible?

I am just using this generic code for the t-test:

```
t.test(EAR_L, EAR_R, mu=0, alt="two.sided", paired=T, conf.level=0.95)
```

Comment: Hello lisa, please post a sample of your data using `dput(your_sample_data)` and copying the output in your question, and explain in more detail what is the desired result.

Comment: Something like `i <- sex == "M"` and then subset `EAR_L[i]` and `EAR_L[!i]` to test left ear males vs females. Or `EAR_L[i]` and `EAR_R[i]` to compare males' left and right ears. The same applies to females negating the index `!i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you ever heard about Chat GPT? Here is the response to your question from this engine,

```
# Run t-test on overall dataset
t.test(EAR_L, EAR_R, mu=0, alt="two.sided", paired=T, conf.level=0.95)

# Subset data by sex
male_data <- subset(data, Sex == "male")
female_data <- subset(data, Sex == "female")

# Run t-test on male subset
t.test(male_data$EAR_L, male_data$EAR_R, mu=0, alt="two.sided", paired=T, conf.level=0.95)

# Run t-test on female subset
t.test(female_data$EAR_L, female_data$EAR_R, mu=0, alt="two.sided", paired=T, conf.level=0.95)
```

Comment: I have not. Thank you for this - it worked perfectly. So simple.

Comment: Very interesting! Do you have a source URL that you used to let ChatGPT generate this code?